# How would I determine the index of the last item in javascript array with a value > 0

Tags: javascript, jquery

As my question states how would I determine the index of the last item in JavaScript array with a value > 0

So if myarray = `[12, 35, 56, 0, 42, 0]`

How would I find the index of the **last** positive integer in this array? i.e in this instance the answer would be 4 (no. 42).

Comment: Just loop through and check each number

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no shortcut, just loop backward through the array from `length - 1` to `0` (inclusive) and stop at the first `>0` entry.

Comment: Really... why did I add an answer with some code. This answer is just the right one.

Comment: Thanks T.J.Crowder, this is what I shall do.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var array = [12, 35, 56, 0, 42, 0];
function getLastNotZero(array){
    var t = 0, i = array.length-1;
    while(t <= 0 && i >= 0){
        t = array[--i];
    }
    return i-1;
}
getLastNotZero(array);
//Returns 4
```

Comment: It needs to find a value >0 not !0

Comment: I see you've fixed the `=` vs. `==`, which is good. Mind you, this is still an infinite loop. *Edit* Ah, now you've fixed that too.

Comment: There, the single `=` was a typo, seemingly cost me this answer :/. This wasn't a infinite loop, though.

Comment: The version in place when I commented had no check on `i`. I suppose the loop would have broken eventually, as `undefined <= 0` is false.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
for(var i=myarray.length-1; i>=0;i--){
    if(myarray[i] > 0){
       alert(i);
       break;
  }
}
if(i<0)
alert(i);
```

Comment: You need to go backwards through your array, not forwards.

Comment: @LeeTaylor: Technically, the above works (because he doesn't break the loop until the end). It just works a ***lot*** harder than necessary.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - This is true.

Answer (score 0):

this should do it:

```
var myarray = [12, 35, 56, 0, 42, 0];
var found = {};
found.value = 0;
found.index = 0;
var j = myarray.length;
for (j; j>0; j--) {
    if (myarray[j] > 0) {
        found.value = myarray[j];
        found.index = j;
        break;
    }
}
alert(found.index);
```

EDIT: note the above would not clarify the 0 index or none so:

```
found.value = undefined;
found.index = undefined;
var j = myarray.length;
for (j; j>0; j--) {
    if (myarray[j] > 0) {
        found.value = myarray[j];
        found.index = j;
        break;
    }
}
alert(found.index);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
var myarray = [12, 35, 56, 0, 42, 0], index;
$.each(myarray,function(idx,el){
    if(el > 0){ 
        index = idx;
    }
});
alert('Index:'+index+', value:'+myarray[index]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the reverse index with `.reverse()` and `.findIndex`, then do some basic arithmetic to flip it:

```
> myarray = [12, 35, 56, 0, 42, 0]
> var ridx = myarray.slice().reverse().findIndex(n => 0 < n)
1
> var idx = myarray.length - 1 - ridx
4
```